# BitSet out of memory Java

Tags: java, bitset

I am using BitSet to keep track whether nodes in a Graph have been visited using DFS method. For this purpose I have created a BitSet[] array. The BitSets themselves can be between 100.000-500.000 entries.

This is the code I am using.

```
   public void tc() {
//        if (scc_cache_valid)
//           return;
        marked2 = new BitSet[node_count];
        for (int v = 0; v < node_count; v++) {
            //if (marked2[v] == null)
                marked2[v] = new BitSet(edge_count);
            System.out.println("aaa" + marked2[v].size());
            for (int w : children.get(v)) {
                if (!marked2[v].get(w))
                    dfs(v, w);
            }
        }
    }

    public void tc(int v) {
//        if (scc_cache_valid && marked2[v] != null)
//            return;

//        marked2 = new BitSet[node_count];
//        for (int v = 0; v < node_count; v++) {
        if (marked2[v] == null)
            marked2[v] = new BitSet(node_count);
        System.out.println(marked2[v].size());

        for (int w : children.get(v)) {
                if (!marked2[v].get(w))
                    dfs(v, w);
            }
//        }
    }

    public boolean reachable(int v, int w) {
        return marked2[v].get(w);
    }

    private void dfs(int v, int w) {
        marked2[v].set(w, true);
        System.out.println(marked2[v].length());

        for (int z : children.get(w)) {
            if (!marked2[v].get(z))
                dfs(v, z);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I am running out of heap. Is there a better (more memory efficient) solution to this problem ?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you extended the heap-space of your JVM? By default the max-settings is quite low.

Comment: How many true/false values in total do you actually need to store?

Comment: So you're basically having a matrix of 500,000x500,000? That would take 31,250,000,000 bytes. A bitmap is better for non-sparse data.

Comment: I cannot change the heapsize as it is executed on another server which cannot control.

Comment: I cannot change the heapsize as it is executed on another server which cannot control.

I need to store for a graph of 50.000 nodes. 50.000 BitSets each in worst case with 50.000 true/false values

Comment: It is sparse data. So is it better to use another datastructure with similar performance but better memory footprint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your DFS algorithm is incorrect.

- A classic DFS algorithm for a tree doesn't require a bitmap at all.
- A classic DFS algorithm for a DAG or a full graph requires a single bitmap with a one bit for each node in the graph.  This assumes that there is a (dense) one-to-one mapping from nodes to integers; e.g. node numbers.  If not, then it is conventional to use a `HashSet<Node>`.

In either case, the space requirement is `O(N)` rather than `O(N^2)`.

A pseudo-code algorithm for the DAG / graph case is:

```
 dfs(root) = dfs0(root, new Set());
 dfs0(node, visited) = 
      if !visited.contains(node):
          visited.add(node)
          // do stuff for node
          foreach n in node.children:
              dfs0(n, visited)
```

Note: there is only one Set object used in the traversal.

Comment: Thank you. But I need to find for each node in the graph all its children and store it. Wouldn't I need a separate BitSet for each node ?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Anyhow, that is not what a DFS algorithm does, and your Question *says* you are trying to implement DFS. Why don't you explain clearly in the Question what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to find whether there exists a path between any 2 nodes of the DAG.

Comment: Do you mean Graph or DAG?

Comment: Thank you Steven! You saved me. I overlooked the bit that its faster to search than to store... Now I just dfs search from the source to find whether it hits the node it should connect to.